# Is there a good HTML Meta tags overview somewhere?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Is there somewhere on the Internet a list of common meta tags that can be included in the header of any HTML page? There's [this site](http://vancouver-webpages.com/META/) but it's not working properly. Anything better than this?

Comment: The site you reference seems to be working just fine.

Comment: The site I refer to seems to work, yes. But many tags are just listed there without description. Check "Last-Modified" for example. You can click on the related link but it won't find it in the list of descriptions. Besides, the three frames and the JavaScript stuff tends to weird things on my IE7 and Chrome browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) page. And, of course, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element). Or were you looking for something a little different?

***UPDATE:*** Ah, okay. How about [this](http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags) site? It seems to talk about a lot of the things, maybe that will help. *(If you click on any of the "Click here for more information" links, they explain more stuff about the specific meta tag.)*

Comment: W3schools seems more to explain what this meta tag is. I know what it is, but want to know the most common tags that are in use. This is useful when I want to define my own tags, but it never hurts to know what other tags are used for. http://vancouver-webpages.com/META/bycount.shtml has a list of most used meta tags, but no description. "pics-label" seems very popular but what's it used for? And what about the other values?

Comment: I suppose description of common/uncommon meta values are asked for

Comment: http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags is more useful indeed. Thanks! It's still a short list, though but then, I guess there aren't really that many common meta tags after all.

Comment: Yea, it seems to give a good description of what the tags are, and then links to the W3C page for more information on the standards.